# Why isn't my roti soft?

Tags: flour, indian-cuisine

I have tried this recipe but i want roti more soft.

Roti recipe

- 500 g Wheat flour
- 15 g Salt
- 50 g Oil
- 300 g Water or as required

Comment: We don't do recipe requests here. Instead, tell us what happens when you make this recipe. It is not soft enough? Describe the way you prepare and cook it (mix by hand or machine? knead for how long?) Someone may be able to suggest a change that would result in softer rotis.

Comment: relevant - https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/2181/how-do-i-make-soft-chapattis

Answer (score 1):

Cover roti immediately with a cloth to keep warm, and soft. Cooking too low a heat will make dry roti. Did you knead and allow the dough to rest - it absorbs the liquid better and makes a smoother dough.

Answer (score 1):

To make your Roti (chapati) soft, you can follow the steps as below,

(Highlighted few of important points)

1. Make semi-stiff dough. Not too soft and not too thick.
2. Put some drop of oil on this dough so that it doesn't form
   crust.
3. Cover this up and give it 15 minutes time. It absorbs water in flour better **(important step)**
4. After 10 minutes, Press it by hand so that you will confirm its
   smoothness.
5. After it turns out to be nice and soft, divide it into small lemon
   size bolls
6. Take 1 boll and roll it (oval shape)
7. Apply some oil (3 to 4 drops), sprinkle some dry flour over it.
8. Make it 2 or 3 folds. (**important step for softness and layers of Roti**)
9. Put into dry flour, again start rolling it upto the end
10. Roast it to medium to high heat
11. It you will get nice golden color from both the side.
12. Apply some oil or ghee.

Now, you can see, you will get 3 layers in your Roti which is the proof of its softness.